# Formatting dynamic range as text

Tags: vba, excel

I'm writing a makro formatting all non-numeric cells to text before loading to database. I have a line that I have no idea what's wrong with. My VBA skills are poor. I get run-time error '424'.

```
Sub formatAllCellsAsText()

    Dim wsTemp As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastColumn As Long
    Dim StartCell As Range
    For sht = 3 To Worksheets.Count
        Set wsTemp = Sheets(sht)
        Set StartCell = Range("A4")
        LastRow = wsTemp.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
        LastColumn = wsTemp.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Columns.Count
        For Each Cell In wsTemp.Range(StartCell, wsTemp.Cells(LastRow, LastColumn)).Cells

        If Not IsEmpty(Cell.Value) And IsNumeric(Cell.Value) And InStr(wsTemp.Cells(1, Cell.Column), "Client ID") <= 0 Then

            Dim Temp As Double
            Temp = Cell.Value
            Cell.ClearContents
            Cell.NumberFormat = "@"
            Cell.Value = CStr(Temp)
          End If
        Next
    Next sht
End Sub
```

Comment: Always helps to indicate exactly which line throws the error

Comment: You should really include the vowel in `sht`. It can be crucial.

Comment: Besides telling us which line triggers the error, also please include the *text* of the error. We can't always remember which text belongs to which error number!

Comment: @Tim: I was trying to indicate the error line separating it with empty lines from the rest. I think there's a better way but I haven't learnt it yet. btw, thanks for your reply - it's helpfull but did not solve the error

Comment: @Cindy: The error is 'Object required'

Answer (score 1):

```
Set StartCell = Range("A4")
```

should be

```
Set StartCell = wsTemp.Range("A4")
```

Answer (score 0):

Just want to summarize as I probably found the issue. 
In my first code posted I did not set Cell variable that I was later referring to. I thought that Cell would be self-explanatory for VBA.